# Does an R alternative to the train.columns call in the pandas Python library exists?

Tags: r, dplyr

Are there alternatives in R for the python snippet below? What are some alternatives that exists in R that the community can recommend?

For example (in Python):

```
train.columns = [i.replace(' ', '_').lower() for i in train.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, in python:

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A a','B b','Cc'])
train.columns = train.columns.str.replace(' ','_')

train.columns
Index(['A_a', 'B_b', 'Cc'], dtype='object')
```

In R:

```
train = data.frame(list('A a'=NA,'B b'=NA,'Cc'=NA),check.names=FALSE)
colnames(train) = gsub(" ","_",colnames(train))
colnames(train)
[1] "A_a" "B_b" "Cc"
```

Comment: no problem. yes you can do without the list comprehension